# Using HttpClient to perform query count api search Elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, httpclient, querydsl

I am wanting to use httpclient in order to perform a GET /count in elasticsearch to return how many hits there are based on a query search. However, I am stuck on trying to get the value inside of `jsonData` which contains the following when debugging and hovering over `jsonData`:

```
{{
  "count": 91,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  }
}}
```

I know this can be doing using the count api with NEST. But I am wanting to do it with httpclient. So I tried the following, but when I set `count = contents.Count()` it returns 72 and not 91.

```
       var countQuery = "{ \"query\": { \"bool\": { \"should\": [ { \"match\": { \"fields.User\": \"jukl\" } } ], \"filter\": [ {" +
            " \"range\": { \"@timestamp\": { \"gte\": \"2021-07-01T00:00:00.000-05:00\", \"lt\": \"2021-07-31T23:59:59.999-05:00\" } } } ]," +
            " \"minimum_should_match\": 1 } } }";
```

**How do I go about assigning `count` to hold the value 91?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elastic for .NET documentation itself states that it is not a good practice to use the HttpClient to consume.
The correct thing would be to use dependency injection, like the example below:

```
public static void AddElasticsearch(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:uri"]));

    var defaultIndex = configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:defaultIndex"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(defaultIndex))
        settings = settings.DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var basicAuthUser = configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:username"];
    var basicAuthPassword = configuration["ElasticsearchSettings:password"];

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(basicAuthUser) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(basicAuthPassword))
        settings = settings.BasicAuthentication(basicAuthUser, basicAuthPassword);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(client);
}
```

Afterwards, use the code below to get the total of records:

```
var search = new SearchDescriptor<T>(IndexName).MatchAll();
var response = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<T>(search);
if (response.IsValid)
{
    return response.Total;
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/hgmauri/elasticsearch-with-nest

Comment: If you do not mind, can you please share with me the documentation for the .NET that says that. I would like to read more into that. This way that you are doing, this is a doing the same thing as using NEST but dynamically correct?

Comment: Follow the link: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/lifetimes.html
And yes, the correct thing is to always use Elastic in .NET with the NEST package, for knowing how to work the connections with elastic.

Comment: I do not see where it says not to use httpclient in the article you provided? In the updated post is that dynamically?

Comment: In fact, the documentation indicates using NEST because it controls the connection with elasticsearch, making your application more performartic.

Internally, NEST uses HttpCLientFactory to manage connections: https://thinkrethink.net/2018/07/25/httpclient-httpclientfactory-asp-net-core

Comment: @MarkCo If you are actually going to use HttpClient, I suggest using HttpClient to manage your connections, this way you avoid a memory leak